# How to create silverlight app with vwd 2008 sp1?

Tags: .net, silverlight

I've installed Visual Web Developer express 2008 sp1 and Silverlight 3 Tools.
But I only have two new VS templates "Silverlight Script Web" and "WCF Service".
How do I create a Silverlight application?

I have c#, vb.net, vwd express editions and visual studio 2005.

Please Help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Web Developer Express is the preferred method of Silverlight development. You don't need the C# or VB.NET express editions.

Make sure that you're running the latest (SP1 included) Visual Web Developer Express 2008. After installation, install the Silverlight Tools (v3). Confirm that you also have the Silverlight SDK and all that on your machine.

It just works, and you'll find the project templates under the language of choice - Visual C# or Visual Basic, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Larry also make sure you are choosing New Project instead of New Web Site.